# Remove app from Appstore and Upload new app with same name

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I had an App in Appstore, i need to remove the app from sale and upload that as new app or record with same name. But i am unable to give the same name, it's showing an alert like this,

> The app name you entered is already being used. If you have trademark
>   rights to this name and would like it released for your use, submit a
>   claim.

Is there any quick process to solve this? Please advise.

Thanks in advance

Comment: is Andrea Mugnaini's solution worked??

Comment: Yes it worked !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say your app is called `Awesome` with current version `v1.0.0`, I think you might try to follow these steps:

1) Rename your current live app in something like: `Awesome App`

[image]

2) as explained in the image, to be able to see the changes you have to release a new app version, let's do it with `v1.0.1`

3) wait for approval, then as soon as it's on the store, submit for the first time the new app (with a new bundle identifier and so on) called `Awesome`.

4) finally you should remove from the store `Awesome App`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that name is locked permanently and you have to choose another name. According to App Store Review Guidelines:

> 2.3.7 Choose a unique app name...

More info [here](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/).